# How to use author id in post permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Currently, Wordpress supports author name in the post permalink by using %author%.

Is it possible to add the author id to the permalink?

For example, changing this:

http://www.site.com/john/my-first-post

to this:

http://www.site.com/1/my-first-post

Where '1' is the id of the author 'john'.

Comment: Seems more like a wordpress question that a php one. (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can put author id in a parameter, and then some `.htaccess`

Comment: For follow the question in wordpress.stackexchange.com here´s the [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/112719/42793)